# why isn't chrome accepting bottom: 0; as a value for an absolutely positioned footer?

Tags: html, css

not actually sure this is only a chrome problem, but i've got this entire page set up with absolutely positioned elements within a container that's position relatively. normally, i wouldn't do this, but we needed rotating images, so we couldn't use the css background property.

anyways, for some reason, when i position the footer absolutely with a position of bottom: 0; right: 0; it doesn't show up.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 940px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 350px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

EDIT: We cannot set the height of the wrapper, as this is going to be a wordpress site, and the user could put in a ton of text. we can, however, set the height of footer.

Comment: Does the content show up, with no height set on wrapper and all absolute items inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unable to set a height then just remove the footer from the wrapper so it has no parent.  Absolute positioning height is determined from its parent.  You parent "wrapper" has no height; therefore, it won't float to the bottom.

Luckily body will go to the bottom.

here's the code in [jsFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/cy5ue/11/)

```
        #wrapper {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 940px;

    }

    #content {
          background:#ccc; 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 350px;

    }

    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
        background:papayawhip;
    }​



    <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
      sdfasdf
  </div>

</div>
 <div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>aslfaskdjf</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
​
```

Comment: how can i get it to stay on the right side of the wrapper?

see: http://guardianwebtest.edulence.com/model15/

Comment: you want it in the 960px yes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cy5ue/28/  i've changed the code you can figure it out from here.  good luck

Answer (score 2):

The height of `#wrapper` is `0px` so the `#footer` does show up - but its `0px` height .... [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ5Vu/1/) you will notice that the `#footer` is a red border on the right

If you give the `#wrapper` a height and apply a height to `#footer` [you can see it](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ5Vu/) or to make the footer the same height as its contents [remove its height property](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ5Vu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it above code true but, your #wrapper has relative position and your #footer inside #wrapper. the position of #footer is aligned according to wrapper.If you  give height to wrapper you can see it ;See below;

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <ul>
your_content
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 940px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 350px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

You can see example here http://jsfiddle.net/8DZ5R/

Another way to solve this, simply change "#footer" position "absolute" to "static".You dont need to change wrapper height: You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/8DZ5R/1/